# Совпадение координатов js

Tags: javascript, dom

У меня есть яблоко и корзинка, яблоко падает с верху в низ и корзинкой нужно словить это яблоко, помогите пожалуйста сделать проверку на совпадение координат.

```
let corzinka = document.querySelector(".corzinka"),
    apple = document.createElement("img"),
    body = document.querySelector(".body"),
    y = 8,
    xApple = "",
    x = 0;
    apple.classList.add("apple");
    apple.src = "./Screenshot_1.png";
    body.appendChild(apple);
    console.log(apple);

    document.onkeydown = function(event){
        if(event.key == "ArrowRight"){
            corzinka.style.marginLeft = x+"px";
            x=x+40;
        }
        if(event.key == "ArrowLeft"){
            corzinka.style.marginLeft = x+"px";
            x=x-40;
        }
    }
    setInterval(function(){
    y = y + 20;
    apple.style.marginTop = y+"px";
    },100);

    if(apple.getBoundingClientRect() == corzinka.getBoundingClientRect()){
        apple.remove();
    }
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/q97ou1dp/

Comment: Спасибо,но оно работает только когда я двигаю мышкой, как сделать так что бы оно выполнялось всегда?

Comment: ну вы используете `setInterval` для смены позиции яблока, там и делайте проверку